# JavaScript Display current array index's value in div and keep updating till end of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Onclick, I want each of the words from the textarea string to be displayed at intervals (e.g 3secs) in the "stringResult" div.Thanks.

```
<form>
<textarea id='inputString'></textarea>
<br/>
<input type='button' value='submit' onclick='Read(); '>
</form>

<div id='stringResult' >
display result
</div>
<script>

function Read(){
var inputArray=(document.getElementById('inputString').value).split(' ');

for(var i=0;i<inputArray.length;i++){

 //setTimeout(something i guess,3000);
document.getElementById('stringResult').innerHTML=inputArray[i];

}


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function that displays the next element of the array, and call it every 3 seconds with `setTimeout`.

```js
function Read() {
  var inputArray = document.getElementById('inputString').value.split(' ');
  var i = 0,
    len = inputArray.length;
  displayCurrent();

  function displayCurrent() {
    if (i < len) {
      document.getElementById('stringResult').innerHTML = inputArray[i++];
      setTimeout(displayCurrent, 3000);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id='inputString'></textarea>
  <br/>
  <input type='button' value='submit' onclick='Read(); '>
</form>

<div id='stringResult'>
  display res
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this function instead of yours

```
function Read(){
    var inputArray=(document.getElementById('inputString').value).split(' ');

    function DisplayText(index){
        if(index >= inputArray.length)
            return;


        document.getElementById('stringResult').innerHTML=inputArray[index];
        setTimeout(DisplayText,3000,index+1);
    }

    setTimeout(DisplayText,3000,0);
}
```